# 3D model with name labels in Google earth API?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-plugin

My Probrems:
I'm Success display a 3D-Model.
but name label is does not appeared.

My Code:

```
var me = this;
var model = ge.createModel('');
var placemark = ge.createPlacemark('');
placemark.setName(name);
me.placemark = placemark;
ge.getFeatures().appendChild(placemark);
```

How can I display a Model with NameLabel?

like this..
http://www.rodbearden.com/RadarBox/3Dsample.gif

thx.

Answer (score 0):

The name field in the placemark object is a bit misleading.  Just setting the field does not mean the name will be displayed.  To get the name displayed, you'll need to associate an icon with the placemark.  You'll need to setup an icon to go with the placemark.  See the docs page 
https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/placemarks#custom

Comment: thaks dolphus333. Your advice was very helpful.

I Tried using placemark of custom icon. (I made customIcon placemark paired with 3DModel placemark) but the label stick to surface. Altitude is ignored.

Please tell me if you know how to get name-Label in air.

Comment: I forgot about Altitude Mode.
Where I set it, my code worked correctly.
thx for your help!